# Accessing a member of JSON provider type

Tags: json, f#, pipe, type-providers

I would like to simplify the following block of code to get rid of the `let` expression

```
let jsonFeed = feed |> Fbjson.Parse
jsonFeed.Data 
|> Seq.head 
|> isPromotion triggerInterval
|> getDecision
```

Instead I would like to pipe all the way through right from `feed`. How do I specify the `Data` member to be passed to `Seq.head` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done with a lambda-expression:

```
feed |> Fbjson.Parse 
|> (fun f -> f.Data)
|> Seq.head 
|> isPromotion triggerInterval 
|> getDecision
```

That said, I really don't understand the desire to get rid of `let`. If you're worried about polluting the namespace, you can always hide it within a nested block:

```
let decision =
   let feedData = feed |> Fbjson.Parse 
   feedData.Data
   |> Seq.head 
   |> isPromotion triggerInterval 
   |> getDecision
```

Comment: Thank you! The lambda was the solution I was looking for. I did try it but somehow the intellisense was not suggesting the accessible members so I thought I had it wrong. Once built it started to work correctly.